# generate varname in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, variables

In PHP it's easy to create variables.

```
for($i=1; $i<=$ges; $i++) {
  ${"q" . $i} = $_POST["q".i];
  ${"a" . $i} = $_POST["a".i];
}
```

The result is $a1 = $_POST["q1];

How is the right way for that in jQuery?
I need to create it dynamicly for an ajax dataset.

```
for (var i = 1; i < ges; ++i) {
    var finalVar = "input[name='a" + i + "']:checked";
    var qtext    = $("#q"+ i).text();
    if ($(finalVar).val() == null) {
        qvar = 0
    } else {
        qvar = $(finalVar).val();
    }
    //write question text and value in q1, a1, q2, a2,...

    //generate ajax data        
    params = params + "q" + i + ":" + "q" + i + ", " + "a" + i + ":" + "a" + i + ","
}
```

I want to set the question text in q1 and the answer in a1.

Comment: Generally you don't do that at all in javascript, you use an object with keys and values instead.

Comment: Also note that jQuery's `val()` never returns `null`

Comment: @adeneo I'm a bloody beginner sorry.  So I should lookup keys and vaules. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if am not wrong you want to accumulate answers related to questions from the HTML and want to send the data through ajax..
So u can do something like this:

```
var QnA = {};
$('.eventTrigger').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

    $('#parent').find('.QnA').each(function() {
       QnA[$(this).find('.Que').text()] = $(this).find('.Ans').val();
    })
  console.log(QnA);
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jt4ow335/1/

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you for the snipped. This should work for me.

Comment: Glad I could help you. Cheers! :D

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you can do about it, is:

```
var obj = {}

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    obj['cell'+i] = i

console.log(obj)
```

and pass obj as data